# Access Copying data from one database to another

Tags: ms-access-2007

I need to copy the data from one database to another. However, while copying I need the ID values from the source database to be retained. Is there a way to do it? I tried copying the data but the id values get the new values causing my queries / reports to function incorrectly.

Help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should have thought of this earlier. I ended copying the tables into my current database and then did the INSERT INTO table SELECT * SQL and that helped retain the id numbers when importing.